# Automatic detection of default gateway is wrong

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, routing, gateway

I'm running Debian Jessie on RPi3 (Raspbian). The network connection is on wlan0. Usually, after filling the wpa_supplicant.conf fields, rebooting the network services leads to a working Internet connection.

On my machine I cannot reach anything outside the router because a wrong default gateway.

After a reboot this is my `route -n` output:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

but the gateway is 192.168.1.254. In fact if I type:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.254 wlan0
```

this is the new routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and the Internet connection is now working.
I never needed to manually set the default gateway.

Perhaps I need any other service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default gateway is the router that you sent packets to when you don't have any other router to sent them to. There should only ever be **one** default gateway.

After you reboot, you can see that the default gateway has been set to 192.168.178.1 which can be reached out of the eth0 interface.

I'm not sure whether you statically assigned IP details to eth0 or whether it also uses DHCP, however when wlan0 initiates, it will receive its IP details but will find a default gateway already in the routing table and so won't add another entry.

If wlan0 is the only network connection to be used, you will need to remove the IP details from eth0.

Comment: You're right. The problem was the static ip on eth0. I accept your answer because it solves my problem. I understand it's a bit off-topic, but I kindly ask if it's possible to set anyway a static ip for eth0. The goal is to have a way to reach the machine if wlan0 doesn't connect.

Comment: Absolutely, you can set some static IP details for eth0, but just leave off the default gateway. I would do this by first editing the interfaces file `nano /etc/network/interfaces` and setting the eth0 block as follows [eth0 config](http://i.imgur.com/BPTYhdn.png). Whenever you boot the server, eth0 should have those details but your default gateway located out of wlan0.